# Output php form data as query string appended to url

Tags: php, forms

I have a php form with two fields (initial and surname), after submission this needs to open a link on an external website with the form data forming part of a query string.

If the user inputs John Doe the current form strips out the first and last part of the query string and inputs the input name. This results in `http://example.com/?initial=John&surname=Doe` instead of the desired `http://example.com/?method=boolean&query=john+doe&othermeta&etc`

Current form:

```
<form class="form" action="http://example.com?method=boolean&query=<?php $_POST['initial']; ?>+<?php $_POST['surname']; ?>&othermeta&etc" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="initial" value="" required />
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="" required />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Q1: Why do you need `$_POST['initial']` and `$_POST['surname']` exactly, since you change them by entering values in the textboxes? Do you want them as default values in the textboxes? Otherwise they have no sense in the `action` attribute. So, what is it, please? Q2: Do you really need to pass the concatenated "<initial>+<surname>" in query string? So, is it ok if you have `initial=<value>&surname=<value>`, right?

Comment: Q3: Also, can you use jQuery?

Comment: 1) I need to pass two values to a query string that is appended to an external site url that opens on form submission, if `$_POST` is incorrect please advise the best way to generate a query string with these values. 2) yes 3) yes, can use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you want to do that but this answer is might stupid but this will work

```
<form class="form" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="initial" id="initial" value="" required />
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="" required />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="onSubmitForm()">
</form>
<script>
function onSubmitForm() {
    var mainText = "http://example.com?method=boolean&othermeta&etc";
    var initial = document.getElementById('initial').value;
    var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
    window.location.href = mainText+'&query='+initial+"+"+surname;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciated the fact that you're proposing pure javascript implementation instead of a jQuery one.

Comment: The intent is to generate a search on an external site using the query string. Your method seems to submit the form without validation - meaning it will submit an empty form if the user hits submit without entering any data

Comment: @SBWT that's why i say this is stupid cuz you need to make another validation through javascript for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposal - without the need of javascript or jQuery.

But if you want to concatenate `initial` and `surname` values into a `query` variable on submit, then I recommend the method provided by @Gustiawan Ouwawi.

It wasn't clear, how you want to use the `$_POST` variables, so I implemented them as default input values.

```
<form class="form" action="http://example.com/" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="boolean" />
    <input type="text" name="initial" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['initial']) ? $_POST['initial'] : ''; ?>" required />
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : ''; ?>" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="othermeta" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="etc" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This does not open example.com, instead it apended the query string to my existing site. Also, the aim is for only the input to show in the query string seperate by `+`, intent is `john+doe` not `initial=john&surname=doe`